# NoSuchMethodError with Netty on Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, netty, elastic-map-reduce, nosuchmethoderror

I am attempting to run a MapReduce job on spot instances using Amazon's EMR service. The intent is to read files off S3, process them in an MR job, and emit rows to a Cassandra DB in the reducer.

My custom jar runs fine on a single-node Hadoop cluster hosted on my machine, reading files off S3 and sending rows to a cloud-hosted Cassandra cluster.

Running on EMR spot instances, my job completes its map phase without issue then throws the following error during the reduce phase:

```
2013-07-09 17:23:46,598 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child (main): Error running child : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.<init>(IIIIIZ)V
    at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Frame$Decoder.<init>(Frame.java:147)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$PipelineFactory.getPipeline(Connection.java:616)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:212)
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:188)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:111)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:56)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:387)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:211)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:174)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:87)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:609)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$100(Cluster.java:553)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:67)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:94)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:534)
    at com.fullcontact.photo_deduplication.metadata.MetaToCassandraReducer.setup(MetaToCassandraReducer.java:32)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Gradle reports my only netty dependencies are on version 3.6.3, which does have a version of the ctor in question.

What might be different between my machine and EMR that would cause this error? Or might it be something else entirely?

Comment: Even in 2021, I still have to check built'in JARs on the EMR, and exclude them by `compileOnly`.